# YouTubeAPI v3 - "Daily Limit Exceeded" error before my app reaches API quota limit

Tags: youtube-api

Daily, between 11:00PM and 2:00AM EDT, my requests to the YouTube v3 API start failing the "dailyLimitExceeded" error, status code 403. The error always stops at 3:00AM EDT. My app hasn't actually yet reached the 50,000,000 units limit. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
                "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
    }
}
```

This started occurring on May 19th, though my app's API usage hasn't really changed since a few weeks before the 19th. Since the issue started, the most API units my app has used is 44,995,660 out of the allowed 50,000,000. The app usually ends each day between 42,000,000 and 45,000,000 units used. My per-user-limit is 3,000 requests/second/user (I highly doubt the API calls from my users are that dense this late at night).

Any ideas on why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I should note that this doesn't affect all of my users when it happens (I believe less than half), many are able to continue using the app without issue while others are receiving the error.

Comment: It means you have hit your daily quota.  Request that it be extended or cut down on the number of requests.

Comment: My daily quota is 50,000,000 units according to the developer console. I haven't hit that limit yet, with the most units my app has used in a day being around 45,000,000. I should note that when it hits the "limit" it doesn't affect everyone, and many of my users are still able to continue using the app without problem.

Comment: What makes you think you haven't hit the limit?   I suspect you have hit the limit Google developer console isn't 100% actuate when reporting quota.

Comment: Ah, if reporting is inaccurate I guess that would explain it. Though, I'm still worried it's a bug, since it doesn't universally affect all of my users (I'd say less than half). I'll submit an update soon which should reduce API usage, I'll close this post if that fixes it.

Comment: You could do what I suggest test it at Midnight Pacific time it should reset then.

Comment: I am getting this error even on using 10,476,126 of 50,000,000 quota limit. This is new and never happened before, I guess there is some problem with google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube Data API Errors -> [Global Domain Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors)

> dailyLimitExceeded402 A daily budget limit set by the developer has
>   been reached.

Billing status 
This API is limited by the free quota shown below.   [Apply for higher quota](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bmNHyfbz3bHFyaB4CmBSfclQWkTAEuM85n-8OYFY57Q/viewform?formkey=dDdnNVF3aGpuLXV1R2V2Nzg3QjJoZWc6MQ&entry_1000001=1046123799103&entry_1000000=laurly71@gmail.com)

> Quota summary 
>  
>      Daily quota resets at midnight Pacific Time (PT).
>   Free quota  50,000,000 units/day 
>   Remaining   50,000,000 units/day   100% of total 
>   Per-user limit 3,000 requests/second/user

The current quota displayed to you in the Google Developer console is a estimate it is not 100% accurate.  If you are getting the error `dailyLimitExceeded` it means that you have reached your limit for the day and will have to wait until midnight PT time to run again.    This is something you can test by running the request again and seeing that suddenly you have access again.

You need to either extend your quota or reduce the number of requests you make.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. I hope the API usage reporting on the console gets updated to be more accurate.

Comment: trust me its better then it was say 3 years ago.  This is kind of close.  I even went as far as logging requests to Google Analytics application account to track usage :)

Comment: Haha, that sucks. Good thing I wasn't on it back then lol. Hopefully getting it below 40,000,000 reported on the console will be enough to stop hitting into the limit.

Comment: So what is the use of YouTube providing to access videos with this minimum limit.

Comment: Ensuring that we can all use it and not one single developer taking all the server power

Comment: I am checking this error code. But sometimes I receive reason codes **quotaExceeded** or **dailyLimitExceeded**. In this case I disable this key for 24 hours and use another key from another project in the same account. (I can have up to 24 projects) What is the difference between these 2 reason error codes? I currently disable one of my keys based on these 2 codes

Comment: Once you have hit the daily limit then it will be disabled until midnight California time.   If the clients are under the same project in google developer console remember they share the same quota.  If you are logged in as the same user its the same quota.  You can also upload only a few videos a day i cant remember what the limit is off hand